# Is C++17 std::to_chars adding a null terminator?

Tags: c++, c++17, string-conversion

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars

Reference does not say anything about that, but the example is (for me) clearly using a null-terminated string, otherwise how could it know where to end, since `std::array::data` returns only a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <charconv>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 10> str{};
    std::to_chars(str.data(), str.data()+str.size(), 42);
    std::cout << str.data();
}
```

Unfortunately I can't test it myself because AFAIK no compiler supports it yet:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Edit:
Forgot that `str` is initialized with zeros, however question is still relevant.

Comment: From the cppreference link: _"On success, returns a value of type to_chars_result such that ec equals value-initialized std::errc and ptr is the one-past-the-end pointer of the characters written. __Note that the string is not NUL-terminated.__"_ [my bold]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The C++17 specification does not state that `to_chars` adds a NUL terminator:

> All functions named `to_chars` convert `value` into a character string by successively filling the range [`first`, `last`) , where [`first`, `last`) is required to be a valid range. If the member `ec` of the return value is such that the value, when converted to `bool`, is `false`, the conversion was successful and the member `ptr` is the one-past-the-end pointer of the characters written. Otherwise, the member `ec` has the value `errc::value_too_large`, the member `ptr` has the value `last`, and the contents of the range [`first`, `last`) are unspecified.

Nothing is stated about a NUL terminator in that paragraph or in the paragraphs that specifically define the behavior of the individual `to_chars` overloads. Therefore, it does not write one.

The example works, so long as `to_chars` does not produce more than 9 characters. Since `str` is initialized to all NUL characters, anything that is not written into `str` will be left as NUL characters.

---

To add to this, the original paper [P0067R0](http://wg21.link/P0067R0) that proposed it explicitly states that the `to_chars` functions should not NUL-terminate the strings.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that this array is initialized with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by cpprefrence (your first link)

> value is converted to a string as if by std::sprintf in the default ("C") locale.

So no it doesn't add a null terminator, as `sprintf` doesn't either (when inserting the values).

Comment: This example is from cppreference and it does not miss `<charconv>` header :D

Comment: Sorry have overseen that :D. Corrected it.

Comment: The cpprefrence link doesn't contain this sentence, anymore. Besides that - `sprintf` **does** null-terminate the destination buffer.